# Set an environmental variable through command line using batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line

[image]

I want to create a batch file . when i execute the batch file i want environmental variable to be set and keep the command prompt to be running as shown in the image

1. Open a command prompt
2. Set a environmental variable
3. Keep command prompt up and running

Comment: Create a Batch file with these lines: `set TestMode=actual` and `cmd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
::@echo off
set TestModule=Actual

@for %%x in (%cmdcmdline%) do @if /i "%%~x"=="/c" @cmd /k
```